# Shuffle.js filtering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently struggeling with using mutlitple filters with shuffle.js.

I can only get 1 filter to work but I am not able to get multiple filters to work.

I have tried mutliple versions but I looks like it is always filtering on the data-solution.

Is there a way to make it filter not only on the data-solution but also on region. In the feature I would like to even add more filter items. There is a codepen already from shuffle.js but not really an explanation. I cannot get it to work :(

this is my code pen
[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Bent-Becker/pen/ZEVPWXN)

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Shuffle/5.2.1/shuffle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="product_archive">
      <div class="container white_bg">
    <div class="filters_container">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="solution-options">
    
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              <input type="radio" class="input-none" name="shuffle-filter" value="all" checked=""><div class="filter_option_solution"><div class="image_div"></div>All</div>
            </label>
    
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              <input type="radio" class="input-none" name="shuffle-filter" value="Broiler Lighting" checked=""><div class="filter_option_solution"><div class="image_div"></div>Broilers</div>
            </label>
    
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              <input type="radio" class="input-none" name="shuffle-filter" value="Layer Lighting" checked=""><div class="filter_option_solution"><div class="image_div"></div>Layers</div>
            </label>
    
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              <input type="radio" class="input-none" name="shuffle-filter" value="Breeder Lighting" checked=""><div class="filter_option_solution"><div class="image_div"> </div>Breeders</div>
            </label>
    
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              <input type="radio" class="input-none" name="shuffle-filter" value="Pullet lighting" checked=""><div class="filter_option_solution"><div class="image_div">
              </div>Pullet</div>
            </label>
    
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              <input type="radio" class="input-none" name="shuffle-filter" value="Swine Lighting" checked=""><div class="filter_option_solution"><div class="image_div">
        
              </div>Swine</div>
            </label>
    
          </div>
    
    
    <div class="region filter">
      <div class="region_group" id="region-options">
        <input type="radio" id="europe" name="region" value="europe">
        <label for="europe">Europe</label>
        
        <input type="radio" id="us" name="region" value="us">
        <label for="javascript">US</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
        <div clas="product_grid js-shuffle" id="product_grid">
    
    
        <div class="product_grid_item shuffle-item" data-solutions="[&quot;Broiler Lighting&quot;,&quot;Layer Lighting&quot;,&quot;Pullet lighting&quot;,&quot;Swine Lighting&quot;]" data-region="[&quot;Europe&quot;]">
           <div class="product_grid_item_container" >
            <div class="image_product_item"></div>
            <a href="/test">Item1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product_grid_item shuffle-item" data-solutions="[&quot;Broiler Lighting&quot;,&quot;Layer Lighting&quot;,&quot;Swine Lighting&quot;]" data-region="[&quot;US&quot;]">
           <div class="product_grid_item_container" >
            <div class="image_product_item"></div>
            <a href="/test">Item2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product_grid_item shuffle-item" data-solutions="[&quot;Broiler Lighting&quot;]" data-region="[&quot;US&quot;]">
           <div class="product_grid_item_container" >
            <div class="image_product_item"></div>
            <a href="/test">Item2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    
          
      </div>
    </div>

<script>
const Shuffle = window.Shuffle;
const element = document.getElementById('product_grid');
const sizer = element.querySelector('.js-shuffle-sizer');

const shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(element, {
  itemSelector: '.product_grid_item',
  sizer: sizer,
  buffer: 1,
});

let selectedSolutions = [];
let selectedRegions = [];

jQuery('input[name="shuffle-filter"]').on('change', function (evt) {
  var input = evt.currentTarget;
  if (input.checked) {
    selectedSolutions.push(input.value);
  } else {
    var index = selectedSolutions.indexOf(input.value);
    if (index !== -1) {
      selectedSolutions.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  // Apply combined filtering
  shuffleInstance.filter(function (element) {
    const solutions = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-solutions'));
    const regions = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-region'));
    const solutionFilter = selectedSolutions.length === 0 || selectedSolutions.some(s => solutions.includes(s));
    const regionFilter = selectedRegions.length === 0 || selectedRegions.includes(regions[0]);
    return solutionFilter && regionFilter;
  });
});

jQuery('input[name="region"]').on('change', function (evt) {
  var input = evt.currentTarget;
  if (input.checked) {
    selectedRegions.push(input.value);
  } else {
    var index = selectedRegions.indexOf(input.value);
    if (index !== -1) {
      selectedRegions.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  // Apply combined filtering
  shuffleInstance.filter(function (element) {
    const solutions = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-solutions'));
    const regions = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-region'));
    const solutionFilter = selectedSolutions.length === 0 || selectedSolutions.some(s => solutions.includes(s));
    const regionFilter = selectedRegions.length === 0 || selectedRegions.includes(regions[0]);
    return solutionFilter && regionFilter;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You where kinda in the right direction, but the shuffleInstance.filter function needs to be called every time you want to filter. I made an example but with select boxes instead of radio buttons. Please copy this code and alter it if you want.

Also please read the documentation about the filter function and the other functions from shuffle.js [here](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/docs/advanced-filters).

```js
const Shuffle = window.Shuffle;
const element = document.querySelector(".products");
const sizer = element.querySelector('.js-shuffle-sizer');

const shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(element, {
  itemSelector: '.product',
  buffer: 1,
});

let selections = {region: "europe", color: "green"};

function filter() {
    shuffleInstance.filter(element => {
    colors = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute("data-colors"));
    regions = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute("data-regions"));
    hasColor = colors.includes(selections.color);
    hasRegion = regions.includes(selections.region);
    return (hasColor && hasRegion);
  });
}
filter();

$("select#color").on("change", function() {
    selections.color = $(this).val();
  filter();
});

$("select#region").on("change", function() {
    selections.region = $(this).val();
  filter();
});
```

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.products .product .placeholderimg {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Shuffle/5.2.1/shuffle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="color">
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="purple">Purple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<select id="region">
  <option value="europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="us">US</option>
</select>

<div class="products">
  <div class="product" data-colors='["green","orange"]' data-regions='["europe"]'>
    <div class="placeholderimg">image</div>
    <p>Green, Orange and Europe</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product" data-colors='["green","blue", "red", "purple", "orange"]' data-regions='["europe"]'>
    <div class="placeholderimg">image</div>
    <p>All colors and Europe</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product" data-colors='["green","orange"]' data-regions='["us"]'>
    <div class="placeholderimg">image</div>
    <p>Green, Orange and US</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product" data-colors='["purple"]' data-regions='["us"]'>
    <div class="placeholderimg">image</div>
    <p>Purple and US</p>
  </div>
</div>
```